# a for loop to run/stop program

Tags: java, for-loop, char, compare

im writing a program that compares two ints, i want the program to run until the user gets tired and wants to quit, to do so the user will enter q to quit. i want to write a while loop comparing two chars one that the user enters in and the second with 'q' assigned to it. however when i enter q my program crushes why is that and how can i fix it

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class numComp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, b; 
    char key  = 'q';
    System.out.println("enter 'q' to quit program and any other key to start it");

    char btn = 0;
    try {
        btn = (char) System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (btn != key){
    System.out.println("enter two numbers to compare them");
    System.out.println("please enter first number:");
    a = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("please enter second number:");
    b = in.nextInt();

    if (a==b)
        System.out.println("the numbers you entered are the same");
    else if (a>b)
        System.out.println("your first number is greater then your second number by "+ (a-b));
    else
        System.out.println("your first number is smaller then your second number by "+ (b-a));
    }

}

}
```

Comment: And where exactly is the user supposed to enter 'q'? Cause the way I see it, you're only allowing numbers to be entered.

Answer (score 1):

You should your loop something like this:

```
try{  
    btn = (char) System.in.read();
    while (btn != key){
    System.out.println("enter two numbers to compare them");
    System.out.println("please enter first number:");
    a = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("please enter second number:");
    b = in.nextInt();

   if (a==b)
      System.out.println("the numbers you entered are the same");
  else if (a>b)
      System.out.println("your first number is greater then your second number by "+ (a-b));
  else
     System.out.println("your first number is smaller then your second number by "+ (b-a));

   System.out.println("enter 'q' to quit program and any other key to start it again");
   btn = (char) System.in.read();
  } // END OF WHILE LOOP
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also note that you need to again get the input from the user just before the `while` loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

That's because in the while loop, you are scanning integer, but "q" is a character. You need give users a chance to read `btn` **inside** the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `btn` when you check it.
You set it only once before the loop, and never update in.

The exception is because

```
a = in.nextInt();
```

you try to read `int` when you enter a `char`.

You need to add at the end of the loop something like:

```
btn = (char) System.in.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplified program.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // Scanner
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Enter the program
    System.out.println("enter 'q' to quit program and any other key to start it");
    int a, b;
    try {
        char key;
        while ((key = s.next().charAt(0))!='q'){
            System.out.println("enter two numbers to compare them");
            System.out.println("please enter first number:");
            a = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("please enter second number:");
            b = s.nextInt();

            if (a==b)
                System.out.println("the numbers you entered are the same");
            else if (a>b)
                System.out.println("your first number is greater then your second number by "+ (a-b));
            else
                System.out.println("your first number is smaller then your second number by "+ (b-a));
        }
    } catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```